# How to change database column type in entity

Tags: symfony

I would like to change the type of a colum from int to string. I change it in my entity file but when I issue make:migration followed by doctrine:migrations:migrate it does not work. How do I update the dB field type from the entity?

Maybe I am being stupid but I have tried to search to no avail

here is part of my entity:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\RideRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"strava_ride_id"}, message="There is already a ride with this ID", ignoreNull=true)
 */

class Ride
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
     private $strava_ride_id;
```

I want to change this to:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
     private $strava_ride_id;
```

but nothing happens when i run:

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

or

```
 php bin/console make:migration
```

I have tried clearing the cache with:

```
 php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
```

Thank you

Martyn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run your migration successfully you should first generate it. To do so , run `doctrine:migrations:diff`  then run `doctrine:migrations:migrate`

Comment: Thanks but it says there are no changes when I run bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff

Comment: Please update the question with the code from your entity or at least the code of the property that you're changing to `string`

Comment: I have even dropped the table and done a doctrine:migrations:diff and then doctrine:migrations:migrate and the table was still in its original form???

Comment: @MartynW can you run a `doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` ? This will show you what command would be executed if there is any difference between the DB and your entities.

Comment: Okay, it seems I had to physically delete the cache directory in order for it to work.  It is now solved.